# What should "Find. Attack. Exterminate" be in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

So I wanted to create a Japanese motto for our Esports team, seeing that our entire team are all anime fans.

So what is

> Find. Attack. Exterminate.

in Japanese?

None of my friends can agree on which, 根絶します or 駆除 is the correct one, so I would like to see if someone can come up with another word for exterminate, or tell us which one is the correct one to use.

We want to make our motto sound ruthless, unforgiving, and utterly decisive (which is how we play our games).

Comment: 見付けて、打て、全滅しろ。It's not perfect. Somebody may propose something better, but remember that JLSE does not accept direct translation requests.

Comment: @変幻出没 I think that should be 全滅させろ. 全滅しろ sounds a bit like "find, hit and then self-destruct".

Comment: @Earthliŋ, Yes it should, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>(I don't know what an Esports team is—e-sports or just sports...?) Anyway,</sub>

I'd go with

> 捜索、攻撃、根絶。
>   Find. Attack. Exterminate.

Since all are suru-verbs, I don't think you need any conjugations of する.

Alternatively, 捜索、攻撃、駆除 also works, but 駆除 is used for (usually animal) pests and implies that you think of your opponents as "vermin". I think it would portray an attitude that is even more alien to normal Japanese thinking than 捜索、攻撃、根絶 already is.

Comment: E-sports as in video games (Starcraft, League of Legends, etc).

Comment: Isn't "Find" closer to 発見 than 捜索, which is "search for".

Comment: @user4092: "to go find something" is used to mean basically the same thing as 捜索. "Find" has both the result sense of 発見, and the process sense of 捜索.

Comment: 捜索、攻撃、壊滅 has the same problem as an earlier comment using 全滅 because the subject of 壊滅する is the ones who are destroyed.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Oh, you're right! Thank you for pointing this out. I shall get rid of this, then. (And welcome back! As you'll have noticed, you are still the top answerer in the tag [food]...)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and thanks for the welcome. About the food tag…we need more questions about food!

Answer (score 3):

A phrase that might read better in Japanese as more idiomatically natural is 索敵【さくてき】・殲滅【せんめつ】 "search and destroy".  索敵【さくてき】 is literally "finding the enemy", and 殲滅【せんめつ】 is literally "killing everyone, destroying everything so nothing/no one is left".  This combines your "attack" and "exterminate" into one word, which might not quite fit what you were looking for, but 索敵【さくてき】・殲滅【せんめつ】 appears to be the military terminology in Japanese and would thus be more immediately understood.

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents.

There is a famous phrase 見敵必殺.

My choice is 探知・襲撃・殲滅。